# Windows 8 update error

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update, windows-8.1-upgrade

When trying to update my computer to Windows 8.1 I get a message saying it couldn't update, so it restored the previous version and it gave this code 0x800706BA - 0x20003.  I am very computer illiterate but I thought I could at least do an update. Before I could even attempt the update, it said I had to uninstall my security tools that Windows 8 came with.

I thought maybe it was just a one time thing but when I tried to update again, it gave me the same error.

What is happening here?

Comment: Did you try using the Windows Store to update, or did you try using a DVD with Windows 8.1 on it?

Comment: I used the Windows Store.

Comment: Have you installed all available updates?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, this occurs when "an update installation crashes":http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-Update-error-800706BA

They also state that the fix is to restart the system. Try this:

1. Do a hard restart (shut down, wait a few seconds, turn it on)
2. After you sign in to Windows, run Windows Update and install the updates marked "Important" and "Recommended".
3. Restart when Windows Update asks you to
4. Go to the Windows Store and try upgrading to Windows 8.1 again.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution worked like a charm and I appreciate your help.